# Request to API behind traefik times out after 30 seconds

Tags: kubernetes, devops, traefik

I have an API [here](https://apps.peregimenez.com/corstest) to test my Traefik config in my k8s cluster. This API takes a query and sends it back after a delay. This is the command I use to test the API:

```
curl -X 'POST' 'https://apps.peregimenez.com/corstest' -H 'accept: application/json' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H "Origin: https://peregimenez.com" -d '{ "query": "hello there", "sleep":30 }' -i --max-time 60
```

If the delay is under 30 seconds, it works. However, if it is over 30 seconds, I get a `502 Server Error`. The Traefik log shows

```
 time="2023-11-30T11:42:54Z" level=debug msg="'499 Client Closed Re │
│ quest' caused by: context canceled"
```

I've tried setting higher timeouts in the Helm chart, and also setting them to 0 to disable them, but nothing works. Wham am I doing wrong?

This is my chart yaml:

```
ingressClass:
  enabled: true
  isDefaultClass: false

additionalArguments:
  - "--log.level=DEBUG"
  - "--providers.kubernetesingress.ingressclass=traefik"
  - "--ping"
  - "--entryPoints.websecure.transport.respondingTimeouts.readTimeout=300s"
  - "--entryPoints.websecure.transport.respondingTimeouts.writeTimeout=300s"
  - "--entryPoints.websecure.transport.respondingTimeouts.idleTimeout=300s"
  - "--entryPoints.websecure.transport.lifeCycle.graceTimeOut=300s"
  - "--entryPoints.web.transport.respondingTimeouts.readTimeout=300s"
  - "--entryPoints.web.transport.respondingTimeouts.writeTimeout=300s"
  - "--entryPoints.web.transport.respondingTimeouts.idleTimeout=300s"
  - "--entryPoints.web.transport.lifeCycle.graceTimeOut=300s"
  - "--serversTransport.forwardingTimeouts.responseHeaderTimeout=300s"
  - "--serversTransport.forwardingTimeouts.idleConnTimeout=300s"

dashboard:
  enabled: true
rbac:
  enabled: true

providers:
  kubernetesCRD:
    enabled: true

ports:
  web:
    port: 8000
    expose: true
    exposedPort: 80
    protocol: TCP
    nodePort: 32080

  websecure:
    port: 8443
    expose: true
    exposedPort: 443
    protocol: TCP
    nodePort: 32443

service:
  enabled: true
  type: NodePort

requests:
  cpu: "100m"
  memory: "100Mi"
limits:
  cpu: "100m"
  memory: "100Mi"
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems 502 server error is likely due to the context cancellation caused by the client closing the request before the `sleep` delay is complete.

Even though you configured sets the timeouts for the entry points and server transport, which should theoretically solve the issue. However, it's possible that the problem lies elsewhere.

You can try to increase the idle timeout of Traefik or disable the idle connection termination.

You can set the

`--entryPoints.websecure.transport.idleTimeout` and

`--entryPoints.web.transport.idleTimeout` flags to a higher value than 30 seconds to increase the idle timeout.

YAML

```
"--entryPoints.websecure.transport.idleTimeout=300s"
```

```
"--entryPoints.web.transport.idleTimeout=300s"
```

Or you can try you can set the `--entryPoints.websecure.transport.idleTimeout` and `--entryPoints.web.transport.idleTimeout` flags to `0.`

YAML

```
"--entryPoints.websecure.transport.idleTimeout=0s"
```

```
"--entryPoints.web.transport.idleTimeout=0s"
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! It turns out it was just a GKE issue

Answer (score 0):

It turns out it was an issue with GKE. There's a [default timeout of 30 sec](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/ingress-configuration#timeout) on backend services.

I don't know why, but switching from NodePort to LoadBalancer service fixed the timeout issue. This is what my chart config looks like now:

```
ingressClass:
  enabled: true
  isDefaultClass: false

additionalArguments:
  - "--log.level=DEBUG"
  - "--providers.kubernetesingress.ingressclass=traefik"
  - "--ping"

dashboard:
  enabled: true
rbac:
  enabled: true

providers:
  kubernetesCRD:
    enabled: true

ports:
  web:
    port: 8000
    expose: true
    exposedPort: 80
    protocol: TCP

  websecure:
    port: 8443
    expose: true
    exposedPort: 443
    protocol: TCP

service:
  enabled: true

requests:
  cpu: "100m"
  memory: "100Mi"
```